# Run python script from jenkins pipe line and get its returned value

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have `jenkins` pipeline and I am running my `python script` this way:

```
stage('Running python script') {
            steps {
                echo "Run script"
                bat "python D:\\srcipt.py --n 10"
                }
        }
```

So this script run and I can see all it print lines but also I want to get its returned ``.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `returnStdout:true` option.
It will look like

```
def result = bat script: "python D:\\srcipt.py --n 10", returnStdout: true
```